# Select specific columns with average of specific row values using joins in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables table1 and table2, in table1 I am saving the user details and in table2 the ratings he has given which are multiple rows with same table1.id and ratings in rating column, but when I execute the following code it returns only one row and average of all the ratings instead of the specific user. I am little weak at queries, I guess there needs to be Select within Select , but it is CodeIgniter so am not able to do that. Please help

```
 $this->db->select('table1.id,table1.name, table1.email, AVG(table2.rating)');
            $this->db->from('table1');
            $this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.review_id', 'inner');
            $this->db->where(array('table1.status' => 1, 'table1.b_id' => $bid));
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query;
```

What I want is :

```
> id Name  email            AvG
> 
> 1  name1 name1@xyz.com  average of ratings by this id in table2 
> 2  name2 name2@xyz.com  average of ratings by this id in table2
```

but what I am getting is

```
> id  Name email           AvG
> 
> 1  name1 name1@xyz.com  average of all ratings in table2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY`

```
$this->db->select('table1.id, table1.name, table1.email, AVG(table2.rating)');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.review_id', 'inner');
$this->db->where(array('table1.status' => 1, 'table1.b_id' => $bid));
$this->db->group_by(array('table1.id','table1.name', 'table1.email'));
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

**UPDATE** To get correct average when `rating = 0` you can use the fact that `AVG()` doesn't take into account `NULL`s. Therefore you can use `IFNULL()` or `CASE` in your select part

```
$this->db->select('table1.id, table1.name, table1.email, AVG(NULLIF(table2.rating, 0))');
```

A base sql query should look like

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.email, AVG(NULLIF(t2.rating, 0)) rating
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.review_id
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.email
```

Comment: thank you so much, now I am 100% sure I am very bad at SQL.. thank you so much

Comment: peterm, hi can you tell me if there is any way if table2.rating =0, it doesnot get included in average ?

Comment: @Deepanshu You are welcome. And see updated answer for your additional question.

Comment: @Deepanshu Updated the answer. Sorry, typo. Forgot closing parentheses for `NULLIF()`. Try it again with parentheses.

Comment: actually I did that, but it returned nothing

Comment: @Deepanshu Strange. Do you get any error messages? Is your RDBMS actually MySql as stated in your question's tag?

Comment: Well i dont know much, but am using phpmyadmin and it is CodeIgniter, so I suppose the RDBMS being used is MySql

Comment: @Deepanshu Try execute SQL query directly in myphpadmin with exact where conditions and see if you get correct results.